# Multiple rocksdb Instances: Use a Single Shared Cache or Multiple Independent Caches?

Tags: c++, rocksdb

We are opening multiple rocksdb instances into a single process and they are all accessed equally. When using `BlockBasedTableOptions::block_cache` is there any benefit allocating a single large cache over several smaller caches?

With `NewLRUCache` it appears that the `num_shard_bits` allows a single large shared cache to reduce the resource contention just like having multiple smaller caches each with no sharding. From the outside they appear equal.

**Edit**

I think it best for someone to close/delete. There isn't a programing answer to this question. I was attempting to understand conceptually how rocksdb works. This is a question for the rocksdb Google Group not SO.

Comment: When *you* tested / benchmarked this (the different options), what did that tell you?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm looking for insight beyond cycle counts and memory usage to understand why one would choose a shared vs separate caches when usage of all database instances are equal.

Answer (score 0):

A Cache object can be shared by multiple RocksDB instances in the same process, allowing users to control the overall cache capacity.

https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Block-Cache

Comment: Please add some code as to how this can help the OP achieve their goal. https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-answer